# hitting error ruuning rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
ruby script/server
=> Booting WEBrick...
/home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:74:in `establish_connection': Please install the postgres adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgres-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/postgres_adapter) (RuntimeError)
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:392:in `initialize_database'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:139:in `process'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `send'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:112:in `run'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /config/environment.rb:13
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:59
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
    from /home/rao/Documents/homir /vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:49
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you ask questions here, you are expected to put some effort into it (and actually ask a question). What you should priovide with your question is http://WhatHaveYouTried.com

Comment: @user1611081 As you are new to SO, you should ask questions as per SO guidelines (have a look here, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) and should try to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you are using prosgres but you didn't installed its adapter.

Just add `gem 'pg'` in your gem file and run `bundle install`.

Comment: I do not have gem file even bundler in my rails version 2.2.2 then what was the solution please help me out

Comment: I do not have gem file even bundler in my rails version 2.2.2 then what was the solution please help me out

Comment: please specify `pg` gem in your environment file.

Comment: `congif.gem 'pg'` in environment.rb